# SQL Server - Invalid column after sp_rename

Tags: sql-server

I have rename a couple of columns in a table using sp_rename (changed name of column Win).  After that (and even after reopening SSMS), I cannot update an unrelated column.

```
update dbo.tblWinLoss
set [X_1] = 1;
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WinLossChange, Line 174 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'Win'.

I don't have a stored procedure of any such name.  Maybe there is something in the system that didn't get updated?

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: That SQL doesn't reference a column `Win`. Perhaps you have a trigger or computed column on the table that you forgot to update?

Comment: Also, that message says the error is on "Line 174"; your SQL is 2 lines long; clearly the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: That was it.  I don't often write triggers and I wrote one about a year ago...check all stored procedures but not triggers!  Thanks.